# Paypal IPN verification stopped working

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

Site that handles PayPal payments through the IPN API, stopped working today. I use the sample php script provide by paypal to process IPN. After debugging I found that it mas missing the VERIFIED response you receive after submitting the request to confirm a payment notification. And neither was arriving "INVALID".

Finally, after adding code to trace the response, I thought that the actual response had a trailing empty space. This would explain that

```
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
```

would'nt hit. Before that I added

```
$res=trim($res);
```

and things returned to normal -apparenly-. But I wonder if anyone else has experienced this today. (I am not sure of the exact character[s] that were being added but I just know that trimming the response fixed the problem.

Comment: if trim fixes it, then there's whitespace in there.

Comment: Marc, if $res were " VERIFIED" wouldn't trim fix it?

Comment: yep. that's what I said. if running $res through trim "fixes" the problem, then $res has(/had) whitespace in it.

Comment: Uh! right, I guess I'm tired :-)

Comment: Yes, our script died today to. Going to try this fix.

Did I miss a memo on an API change? WTF?

Comment: *Freaking white space* after `$res` made me lose 24 hours of debugging time. How incompetent can PayPal be, to provide this `strcmp()` sample code without `trim()` and then not making sure their server reply is clean.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems. Started on Sunday 7th July 2013, and we just noticed it today. Lot's of records for transactions lost. Thanks for telling us Paypal!

Trimming the $res as mentioned above fixed my IPN script, for now. But I also had problems with my PDT script. The script uses strcmp to look for the response message in the array $lines. It used to be:

```
if (strcmp ($lines[0], "SUCCESS") == 0){}
```

but after examining the array it seems that the response message is now located at $lines[1]. So I had to update to the following to get it to work.

```
if (strcmp ($lines[1], "SUCCESS") == 0){}
```